# How to detect if object is Traversable in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, traversable

How can I detect the variable is a `Traversable` object to use in `foreach` loops?

```
if(is_traversable($variable)) {
    return (array) $variable;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) to determine if the object is `Traversable`

```
if($variable instanceof \Traversable) {
  // is Traversable
}
```

Comment: A teeny note to add that if this code is not in the global namespace it will evaluate to `false` unless Traversable is imported or fully-qualified, so the OP should add `use Traversable;` or use `\Traversable` to their code.

Comment: It should be noted as mentioned in the comments on the Traversable phpdoc page, that objects and arrays can be iterated through with something like foreach but are NOT instances of Traversable.

Answer (score 16):

`is_iterable` can be used since PHP 7.1.

```
// https://wiki.php.net/rfc/iterable
var_dump(
    true === is_iterable([1, 2, 3]),
    true === is_iterable(new ArrayIterator([1, 2, 3])),
    true === is_iterable((function () { yield 1; })())
);
```

Comment: I assume that the traversable checking is to make sure the conditions listed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6251125/859837 are met.

Not too sure but it is_iterable might give you a false positive because arrays are iterable but not traversable.