# Check for iterable content PHP

Tags: php, types, iterator

As for for PHP >= 7.1 it is possible to detect if  a variable is iterable or not using `is_iterable()`.

is there an alternative to this for PHP <= 7  ?

how can i perform this since im working on php 7.0 ?

Comment: Would [traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if object is Traversable in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701517/how-to-detect-if-object-is-traversable-in-php)

Comment: @ManojSalvi the answers for this question don't respect arrays

Comment: @JonStirling thanks Philipp's anwser solved it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have to test, if the given var is of type `Traversable` or if it is an array. Everything else isn't iterable.

```
if (!function_exists('is_iterable')) {
    function is_iterable($var)
    {
        return is_array($var) || $var instanceof \Traversable;
    }
}
```

Comment: cover this function in ´if (!function_exists('is_iterable')) { ... }´ to keep it safe for the future. nobody knows if the provider or somebody else is updating the php version.

Comment: Objects of class `stdClass` are iterable, but are not arrays or instances of `Traversable`.

Comment: @StevenJeffries is_iterable(new stdclass) returns false in php 7.2